# moving in a circular motion from one point to another

Tags: javascript, math

2 points on a 2d grid and I need to move my player in a way that would be a circular motion to the other point gradually what would the equation look like on that?
like moving from point p to point Q would it relate to the differences in the angles and distance? I'm stumped I feel dumb please help!
https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1ykX.png

Comment: `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2` where (a,b) is the point, (x, y) is the player and r is the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Circle center

```
C = (P + Q) / 2
```

Initial radius-vector (from `C` to `P`)

```
A = (P - Q) / 2
```

Perpendicular vector

```
B.x, By = -A.y, A.x
```

Now [SLERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) for `Ω = Pi/2` in  range `t = 0..2`

```
R.x = C.x + sin((1-t)*Pi/2)*A.x - sin(t*Pi/2)*A.y
R.y = C.y + sin((1-t)*Pi/2)*A.y + sin(t*Pi/2)*A.x
```

Quick checking:

```
t = 0: R.x = C.x + 1 * A.x - 0 = P.x
t = 1: R.x = C.x + 0 - A.y = point at the middle perpendicular
t = 2: R.x = C.x - A.x + 0 = Q.x
```

Comment: How would I do the math to get my player (A) to (B) in that circular motion pushing it to collide with (X), I tried projecting (X) coordinates to its angle towards (B) with the distance between (X) and (B) + radius of both circles (A, B) and making it the destination point but the problem is getting (A) to move in that circular motion to avoid collision with X. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1E1F.png

Comment: Moving objects with non-zero size is more complex problem. I am not sure I understand your problem properly. Perhaps you need do calculate circular trajectory center/radius to avoid collision with X object.